# Can't overlay button over Android Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I've tried to follow many answers from other questions with the same problem, but none of them helped me.

I just need to put a button over a Google Map fragment.

Here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context="com.henriquevoni.petgo.MapFragment"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:background="#359c5e"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is an [screenshot of the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGj2Q.jpg)

Comment: Use Android Studio's Layout Inspector to see where your button is winding up.

Comment: On the parent RelativeLayout try change layout_width to match_parent

Comment: Your Fragment is consuming the entire screen. The button is therefore pushed off. Put the button first if you want it "over the Fragment", i believe

Answer (score 0):

Can u try like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
tools:context="com.henriquevoni.petgo.MapFragment"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:background="#359c5e"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"

    />


</FrameLayout>
```

Or u can also do like this

If this is what you want ...simply add button inside the Fragment.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
tools:context="com.henriquevoni.petgo.MapFragment">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:background="#359c5e"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"

    />
</fragment>

</FrameLayout>
```